# Getting numbers separated by a comma, semicolon, or dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I need get numbers  separated by a comma, semicolon, or dot

Input strings can be

> 12345678,12345678,12345678
>
> 12345678.12345678,12345678;12345678

There may be a space before or behind the separator

> 12345678 , 12345678 . 12345678 ; 12345678

There may be a space between the numbers

> 1234 5678 .12 345678, 123 45678 ;12 3456 78

The output should always be

> 12345678 12345678 12345678

It would be nice if I could check if the number has 8 digits

So far I have this regular expression

> [0-9]+(,[0-9]+)+

Need it for Javascript

Thanks for advice

Comment: This looks maybe not possible to me.  What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Javascript

Comment: It seems not possible, in general, to know whether space is a separator character or part of the number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited the post. You are right. Having the space as a separator and having spaces between digits at the same time is not possible

Comment: @Mirau Can you update your question with your comments?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Already done

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check 8 digits with optional spaces, you can match 8 digits with optional spaces in between and use a positive lookahead to assert either a comma, semicolon, or dot at the right.

```
\b\d(?: *\d){7}(?= *[,;.]|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b\d` A word boundary, match a single digit
- `(?: *\d){7}` Repeat 7 times matching optional spaces and match a single digit to make a total of 8
- `(?= *[,;.]|$)` Positive lookahead to assert optional spaces and either a `,` `;` or `.` at the right or the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/suhuw5/1)

Then in the resulting array from match, you can remove the spaces and join the arrays with a space.

```js
const regex = /\b\d(?: *\d){7}(?= *[,;.]|$)/g;
const strings = [
  "12345678,12345678,12345678",
  "12345678.12345678,12345678;12345678",
  "12345678 , 12345678 . 12345678 ; 12345678",
  "1234 5678 .12 345678, 123 45678 ;12 3456 78"
].forEach(s => {
  const res =
    s.match(regex)
    .map(i => i.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
    .join(" ");
  console.log(res);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove space from it.
like :

```
var str = "1234  5678 .  123 45678 , 1 2345678 ; 12 345678"
var patt1 = /\s/g; //regex for space
var result = str.replace(patt1 , "");
```

after removing space you can replace comma, dot, and semicolon.
like :

```
 var patt2 = /[\.;:]/g; //regex for replace comma, semicolon, and dot with space
 var output = result.replace(patt2," ");
```